# Vue 3: How to update component props value correctly using composition api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

I have like this component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Current coords: <strong>{{ coords }}</strong></p>
    <button type="button" @click="updateCoords">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    coords: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const updateCoords = () => {
      props.coords = [38.561785, -121.449756]
      // props.coords.value = [38.561785, -121.449756]
    }
    return { updateCoords }
  },
}
</script>
```

I tried update prop `coords` value with `updateCoords` method but I get error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
> 'coords')

How I can correctly update props value in my case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Props are readonly:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow

If you want to have two way binding for props, you'll need to implement the v-model pattern:
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#_3-x-syntax

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Current coords: <strong>{{ coords }}</strong></p>
    <button type="button" @click="updateCoords">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props, {emit}) {
    const updateCoords = () => {
        emit('update:modelValue', [38.561785, -121.449756])
    }
    return { updateCoords }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update `props` and change it in vue 3 you must right your code according to your code like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Current coords: <strong>{{ coords }}</strong></p>
    <button type="button" @click="updateCoords">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    componentPropsName: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  emits: ['update: componentPropsName'],
  setup(props, {emit}) {
    const updateCoords = () => {
      emit('update:componentPropsName', [38.561785, -121.449756])
    }
    return {updateCoords}
  },
}
</script>
```

but the **main point** is to write your prop in a component in the parent component like this:

```
//parent component 
<child-component v-model:component-props-name="value"/>
```